# Banning AI Generated Content?

Tags: discussion, ai-generated-content

Do we want to ban AI generated content?

[Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1)

or might it actually be helpful here?

In my experience, AI generated answers to devops questions (especially vmware integrations with ansible) have been just wishful thinking.  Both I and the AI wish that these features existed, but only AI has the wherewithal to reference the code that doesn't actually exist. Being human, I would find that a frightfully pointless waste of time.

So maybe answer yes or no to this question and we can go ask the CM's to make us a banner - or we can get no response (like usual) and we'll leave it alone - or simply collude between the pro-tem mods on this.